# How to access/inject the database in a nest.js Auth Guard?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authorization, nestjs

I have a nestjs app that currently has a user and company entity and each company has an owner user.
In my case, I want to write a custom decorator to use in each controller method to see if the user is the owner of that company or not.
so I start writing custom Guard like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class CompanyGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor() { }
    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const user = request.user;
        if (user) {
            console.log(user);
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new HttpException('you have no access to this company', HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
        }
    }
}
```

and I use it like this:

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, CompanyGuard)
@Post('get-data/:companyId/')
getData(@Req() request){}
```

i want to access mongoose database in CompanyGuard and check the access in database how can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

Dependency injection works in `Guards` the same way it does in any other provider (service). So you can just inject the model you want via the constructor:

```
constructor(@InjectModel(Company.name) private companyModel: Model<company>) {}
```